# PySpark Column Get value for concatenating as a string

Tags: python, pyspark

I am writing a python script to categorize some values taken from spark based on age. I need the age group to come like 30-31, 31-32 etc. I have the following code to do the same:

```
user_category = user_filtered.select(user_filtered['UID'], \
                               when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 10, "Female").\
                               otherwise(when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 11, "Male").\
                               otherwise(when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 12, "UNKNOWN").
                               otherwise(""))).alias('Gender'),\
                               when((user_filtered['Age'] >= 18) & (user_filtered['Age'] < 60), str(user_filtered['Age']) + '-' + str(user_filtered['Age'] + 1)).\
                               otherwise(when((user_filtered['Age'] >= 60), "60+"))).alias('AgeGroup').dropDuplicates()
```

This gives the following output:

> abcdefghijk,Female,Column-Column<(Age + 1)>

instead of:

> abcdefghijk,Female,50-51

But when I change the statement to the following:

```
user_category = user_filtered.select(user_filtered['UID'], \
                               when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 10, "Female").\
                               otherwise(when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 11, "Male").\
                               otherwise(when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 12, "UNKNOWN").
                               otherwise(""))).alias('Gender'),\
                               when((user_filtered['Age'] >= 18) & (user_filtered['Age'] < 60), user_filtered['Age']).\
                               otherwise(when((user_filtered['Age'] >= 60), "60+"))).alias('AgeGroup').dropDuplicates()
```

It provides the age value properly, like below:

> abcdefghijk,Female,50

But when I try to make it string for concatenating, it all goes wrong. How can I get the value of the column and concatenate it in the way I require? I am fairly new to python and pyspark.

Comment: You just need to use the lit(user_filtered['Age'])  in place of str(user_filtered['Age'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, concat, when

user_category = user_filtered.select(user_filtered['UID'],
                                     when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 10, "Female").
                                     otherwise(when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 11, "Male").
                                               otherwise(when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 12, "UNKNOWN").
                                                         otherwise(""))).alias('Gender'),
                                     when(user_filtered['Age'].between(18, 60)),
                                     concat(user_filtered['Age'].cast("string"), lit('-'),
                                            ((user_filtered['Age'] + lit(1)).cast("integer")).cast("string")).otherwise("60+")).alias('AgeGroup').dropDuplicates()
```

You can change the type of the column to `string` with `.cast("string")` and not as `str(df["column"])`

Comment: `concat` is imported from `pyspark.sql.functions`, right?

Comment: @Harikrishnan yes it is

Comment: It almost solved the issue, just one minor issue remaining. It now returns `abcdefghijk,Female,50-51.0`, I don't want that `.0` part

Comment: @Harikrishnan cast it to `integer`. This code can get a lot cleaner, tbh. It's difficult to read

Comment: Yeah, need to clean it up. Beginner troubles. Thanks a lot for the help!!! it worked, Had been stuck with it for very long :)

Comment: @Harikrishnan No problem. SO for the rescue

Answer (score 0):

code will be like

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,concat
user_category = user_filtered.select(user_filtered['UID'], \
                       when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 10, "Female").\
                       otherwise(when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 11, "Male").\
                       otherwise(when(user_filtered['Gender'] == 12, "UNKNOWN").
                       otherwise(""))).alias('Gender'),\
                       when((user_filtered['Age'] >= 18) & (user_filtered['Age'] < 60), concat((user_filtered['Age']) , lit('-') , (user_filtered['Age'] + 1)).\
                       otherwise(when((user_filtered['Age'] >= 60), lit("60+")))).alias('AgeGroup').dropDuplicates()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It now returns `abcdefghijk,Female,None`

Comment: @pissall I tried with cast as well. Returned the same result as lit. Any other option?

Comment: @Rahul that also gave `None`